# How to update plot between user inputs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to display several plots in the same Matplotlib window. I want the next plot to appear after user input. The code I am using is inspired from [here](http://physicalmodelingwithpython.blogspot.com/2015/07/displaying-plots-inside-loops.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import jn # Import Bessel function.
def handle_close(evt):
    global closed
    closed = True

fig = plt.figure()
closed = False

def waitforbuttonpress():
    while plt.waitforbuttonpress(0.2) is None:
        if closed:
            return False
    return True

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', handle_close)

r = np.linspace(0,20,101)
plt.ion()

for n in range(10):
    plt.plot(r, jn(n,r))                  # Draw nth Bessel function.
    plt.title("Bessel function J[%d](r)." % n)
    plt.show()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    if not waitforbuttonpress():
        break # Exit loop if user presses a key.
    #plt.cla()                               # Clear axes for next plot.
```

**The problem is that the plot does not update after a key press. What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Try `plt.gca().clear()`

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import jn # Import Bessel function.
def handle_close(evt):
    global closed
    closed = True

fig = plt.figure()
closed = False

def waitforbuttonpress():
    while plt.waitforbuttonpress(0.2) is None:
        if closed:
            return False
    return True

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', handle_close)

r = np.linspace(0,20,101)
plt.ion()

for n in range(10):
    plt.gca().clear()
    plt.plot(r, jn(n,r))                  # Draw nth Bessel function.
    plt.title("Bessel function J[%d](r)." % n)
    plt.show()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    if not waitforbuttonpress():
        break # Exit loop if user presses a key.
    #plt.cla()
```

------------- edit --------------

Since `ax.cla()` is not working for you, you could also try:

```py
for n in range(10):
    # plt.gca().clear()
    lines = plt.plot(r, jn(n,r))                  # Draw nth Bessel function.
    plt.title("Bessel function J[%d](r)." % n)
    plt.show()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    if not waitforbuttonpress():
        break # Exit loop if user presses a key.
    # plt.cla()
    lines.pop(0).remove()
```

Comment: @Theldealis I've tried your code but it behaves the same. It does not update the plot when I press a key. It updates only when the loop ends.

Comment: Strange, it works on my machine. Have you tried another backend?

Comment: @Theldealis ax.cla() is working. The problem is that between user inputs the plot does not update. It updates only when the loop ends. What do you mean by backend? How can I  change it?

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood your question. In my case, every time I press any button the plot is updated. Isn't this the desired behavior?

Comment: @Theldealis Yes, that is the desired behavior. But I don't know why it doesn't update in my case. I noticed that if I manually select tight layout from the plot's menu, it updates. However, using tight_layout() in code has no effect. Similar, if I use other plot controls.